# Grids of a heatmap and a plot on the same figure do not match

Tags: python, matplotlib, alignment, seaborn, heatmap

So I have a figure, which has a heatmap on the top and a plot on the bottom. They both have the same indices(`2020-01-01T00:00:00` to `2020-01-31T23:00:00`). They both have same `xticks` as the start of the day(e.g.: `2020-01-01T00:00:00`, `2020-01-02T00:00:00`, etc...).

However the grids of both the `subplots` seems like not matching.

**Zoomed into the grid:**

[image]

[The complete figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ERSf.png)

Funny thing is if I set the `xlims` of the `heatmap` 1 point smaller, the grids are aligned. I don't understand why. And I also do not want to lose 1 value on my `heatmap`. **So do you have any idea?**

**Here is the code:**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import seaborn as sns

# data
rng = pd.date_range('2020-01-01', periods=744, freq='H')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': rng, 'Val': np.random.randn(len(rng))}).set_index('Date')

# create plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(14, 10))

# bottom plot
ax1 = plt.subplot(212)

# plotting
plt.plot(df.index, df['Val'], label='test')

# grid
plt.grid(zorder=1, linestyle=':', color='black', alpha=1, which='both')

# xlimits and minor ticks
plt.xlim(df.index.min(), df.index.max())  # --> (18262.0, 18292.958333333332)
ax1.xaxis.set_minor_locator(mdates.DayLocator())

# top plot
ax2 = plt.subplot(211)

# heatmap
df_heatmap = pd.DataFrame({'Date': rng, 'Val': 5, 'Val2': 2, 'Val3': 4,
                           'Val4': 8, 'Val5': 10}).set_index('Date')
df_heatmap.index.name = None

sns.heatmap(df_heatmap.transpose(),
            cmap=sns.color_palette(['gray', 'white', 'lightgray']),
            cbar=False, annot=False, xticklabels=24)

ax2.xaxis.set_ticklabels([])
ax2.xaxis.grid(zorder=1, linestyle=':', color='black', alpha=1, which='both')

plt.xlim()  # --> (0.0, 744.0)
# plt.xlim(0, 743)  # fixes the grid problem, but why?

# heatmap frame borders
for _, spine in ax2.spines.items():
    spine.set_visible(True)

fig.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('a.png')
```

Comment: Maybe try using the `sharex` option in your plots

Comment: @RotemShalev when I add `ax2 = plt.subplot(211, sharex=ax1)` and remove the `plt.xlim(index.min(), index.max())`, from the first plot. The first plot does not shown because its `x values` are between `(18262.0, 18292.958333333332)`. And if I put the limits back, then the figure is kinda broken :(